# Wi-Fi Direct file transfer

Tags: android, windows-10, data-transfer

I'm looking for software to transfer files between Windows 10 and Samsung Galaxy S7, using Wi-Fi Direct.

Any suggestions please?

There are some Google Play apps that can do so between two Android devices, but I'm looking for Windows <-> Android.

There are also some apps that work if both devices are on the same Wifi network, but I'm looking specifically for Wi-Fi Direct because it's supposed to work even if the devices are not on the same network - or if somewhere you don't have Wifi connectivity.

What I am trying to achieve is to transfer files even if there's no Wifi around.

Thanks

Comment: look here: https://superuser.com/questions/1595658/transferring-files-between-android-and-pc-via-wi-fi-direct maybe something will help:)

Answer (score 0):

The [X-Plore File Manager](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.lonelycatgames.Xplore) from Lonely Cat Games is all you need. Enable WiFi file sharing, and then enter the IP address of the Android device in a web browser address bar. A file management window appears in that browser on your PC, Mac, or Linux box, and you can transfer files with no additional app on the computer.

Comment: Hi, this only works if both devices are on the same external Wifi network. I'm looking for something that can create it's own Wifi hotspot.

Comment: Then you should edit your question and make this clear.